# The Supremum and Infimum of a sequence of measurable functions is measurable

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory, supremum-and-infimum

I am reading through Folland's *Real Analysis: Modern Techniques and Their Applications*, and they have the following proposition and proof:

> **Proposition:** If $\{f_{j}\}$ is a sequence of $\bar{\mathbb{R}}$- valued measurable functions on $(X, \mathcal{M})$, then the functions:
>
> $$g_{1}(x)=\sup_{j} f_{j}(x)$$ $$g_{2}(x)=\inf_{j} f_{j}(x)$$ are
>   measurable.
>
> **Proof:**
>
> We have
>
> $$g_{1}^{-1}((a,\infty])= \bigcup_{j=1}^{\infty}
>  f_{j}^{-1}((a,\infty])$$ $$g_{2}^{-1}([-\infty,a))=
>  \bigcup_{j=1}^{\infty} f_{j}^{-1}([-\infty,a))$$
>
> Where the result follows from the fact that $g_{1}^{-1}((a,\infty])\in
>  \mathcal{M}$ for all $a \in \mathbb{R} \iff g$ is measurable, and
>   $g_{2}^{-1}([-\infty,a))\in \mathcal{M}$ for all $a \in \mathbb{R}
>  \iff g$ is measurable.

I understand the last part of the proof, but how do we know $g_{1}^{-1}((a,\infty])= \bigcup_{j=1}^{\infty}f_{j}^{-1}((a,\infty])$ and $g_{2}^{-1}([-\infty,a))=\bigcup_{j=1}^{\infty} f_{j}^{-1}([-\infty,a))$? I would appreciate any help with this.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This is the same as Augustin's answer, but to make it psychologically "more tautological"...

Think of unions as 'there exists' [and intersections as 'for all'].

Writing $\{\, P\, \}$ for $\{x\, | P(x) \}$ below:

For instance, in your case,

$$ \{\, \def\S {\sup_k\ f_k} \S >a\, \} = \bigcup_k\ \{\, f_k > a\, \} $$
is the statement that if $\S(x)>a$, then there exists a $k$ such that $f_k (x) >a$, and conversely:  if there exists a $k$ such that $f_k (x) > a$, then ...

Likewise, (not what you are asking, but here for illustration)
$$
\{\, \inf_k f_k\ge a\, \} = \bigcap_k\ \{\, f_k \ge a \,\}$$
is the statement 
that  $\inf_k f_k(x) \ge a $ if and only if $f_k(x) \ge a$ for all $k$.

Comment: This answer (tautological, though it may be) is in memory of Carl Herz.

Answer (score 12):

Hint: $\sup_j f_j(x)\gt a\iff \exists j,\, f_j(x)\gt a$.