Confusion between $\limsup$ and $\liminf$ as intersections or unions of sets
Let $I \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ and $f_n : I \to \mathbb{R}$ be a sequence of continuous functions. Let $a \in \mathbb{R}$ and define:
$$ A = \{ x \in I : \limsup \limits_{n \to \infty} |f_n(x)| \leq a\}$$
I'm a bit confused about how can I write the set $A$ as unions and intersections of sets. For instance, I know that:
$$ \limsup \limits_{n \to \infty} |f_n(x)| = \inf_{j \in \mathbb{N}} \sup_{n \geq j} |f_n(x)|$$
And I've studied that this implies:
\begin{equation}
A = \bigcap_{j \in \mathbb{N}} \bigcup_{n=j}^{\infty} \{ x \in I : |f_n(x)| \leq a\} ... (1)
\end{equation}
(I understand the reason for this equality in terms of set inequalities with $\subseteq$ as partial order).
But why couldn't it be the other way around?, I mean, Why couldn't we have:
$$ A = \bigcup_{j \in \mathbb{N}} \bigcap_{n=j}^{\infty} \{ x \in I : |f_n(x)| \leq a\}$$
I'm asking this because if one thinks of a sequence of functions $F_n: I \to \mathbb{R}$ and if we consider the set:
$$ B = \{ x \in I :  \inf_{n \in \mathbb{N}}|F_n(x)| \leq a \}$$
Then by the definition of infimum we have that $x \in B$ if and only if there exists some $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $|F_N(x)| \leq a$, so:
$$ B = \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} \{ x \in I : |F_n(x) | \leq a \}$$
Thus, couldn't the infimum be represented in (1) as the union of sets instead of the intersection?

not quite what you are asking, but you might find useful https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1456350/the-supremum-and-infimum-of-a-sequence-of-measurable-functions-is-measurable/1456367#1456367

For a sequence of constant functions with values $a+1/n$, all the sets ${|f_n|\le a}$ are empty although ${\limsup |f_n|\le a}=I$. However, $${\limsup |f_n|\le a}= \bigcap_{k\in\mathbb N}\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}\bigcap_{m\ge n} {|f_m|\le a+1/k}.$$

As pointed out by @Jochen in the comments, the equality (1) in the question is  not true.
To understand the order of the intersections and unions, suppose that we have a proposition $P_t(x)$ depending on a parameter $t\in T$ (a set). Then we have
\begin{equation}
\forall t\in T, P_t(x) \Longleftrightarrow x \in \bigcap_{t\in T}\{y:  P_t(y)\}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\exists t\in T, P_t(x) \Longleftrightarrow x \in \bigcup_{t\in T}\{y:  P_t(y)\}
\end{equation}
Hence the quantifier determines whether we have an intersection or a union.
Going back to the question we have
\begin{equation}
\limsup_{n\to \infty} |f_n(x)| \le a \Longleftrightarrow
\forall k\ge 1, \exists j\ge 0, \forall n\ge j, |f_n(x)|\le a + \frac{1}{k}
\end{equation}
Hence
\begin{equation}
x\in A \Longleftrightarrow x\in \bigcap_{k\ge 1}\bigcup_{j\ge 0}\bigcap_{n\ge j} \{y:  |f_n(y)|\le a + \frac{1}{k}\}
\end{equation}
